# How to use WebAPI without ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I would like to use WebAPI for an existing project of mine (classic ASP.NET), but as far as I can tell you can only use WebAPI with MVC.

Is it possible to use WebAPI with ASP.NET?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From the [linked page](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/using-web-api-with-aspnet-web-forms):

> Although ASP.NET Web API is packaged with ASP.NET MVC, it is easy to
>   add Web API to a traditional ASP.NET Web Forms application. This
>   tutorial walks you through the steps.
>
> To use Web API in a Web Forms application, there are two main steps:
>
> Add a Web API controller that derives from the ApiController class.
>   Add a route table to the Application_Start method. Create a Web Forms
>   Project
>
> Start Visual Studio 2010 and select New Project from the Start page.
>   Or, from the File menu, select New and then Project.
>
> In the Templates pane, select Installed Templates and expand the
>   Visual C# node. Under Visual C#, select Web. In the list of project
>   templates, select ASP.NET Web Application. Enter a name for the
>   project and click OK.

Comment: what happened to the link. It was working yesterday but now getting `404 The page you are looking for is not available...`

Comment: I report the link issue and they updated me the new link. I have updated the same in answer.

Answer (score 8):

ASP.NET Web API and ASP.NET MVC live in two *different* worlds albeit *parallel* worlds.

Web API has been designed and built with no dependency to ASP.NET MVC but has been built on the top of ASP.NET.

So the answer to your question - with confidence - is **true**. Brad Wilson himself mentioned this on a podcast recently.

Comment: While informative, this post doesn't actually answer the "how to?" part of the OP's question...